# best ways to add form validations to React Native Forms

Tags: forms, react-native, formvalidation-plugin

I want to add validations to my React Native Form
What is the best approach

Comment: Hi, please provide more explanation what you want to achieve and show what you already have.

Comment: I want to add validations to check if the input is a number or a date or an email and throw error if its not

Comment: Google for Formik & yup in RN

Comment: I did it but i need simple validations it is hard for me to use formik as am new to react native